# Performance issue - Displaying a dynamic HTML table with Nuxt.js

Tags: performance, html-table, nuxt.js, dynamic-arrays, user-experience

I have a large HTML table of data (560 rows and 60 columns) that I display when my application loads.
I had too much display time (5 seconds), I fixed this problem by rendering server side on initial load thanks to Nuxt.js, now the display is almost instantaneous.

The data displayed by this table changes depending on the checkboxes.
The data is collected in a computed property.

My problem is the following: each time a box is checked or unchecked, it is the whole of my data table which is reloaded and re displayed which causes a significant latency between the moment when the box is checked or unchecked and the new display of my table ...

Would there be a way for it to be only the row (s) that are modified by the checkboxes that are modified at the display level and not my entire table.

Comment: `each time a box is checked or unchecked, it is the whole of my data table which is reloaded and re displayed `, why is it working this way? You don't have any `:key`? Also, did you give a read to this one? https://www.maxpou.fr/vuejs-performance-improvement-with-memoization

Comment: Some concrete example w/ code may help too! Or a [repro] of some sort.

Comment: Yes I do have one of the: key otherwise my console would be warning red.
Thank you very much @kissu apparently the problem exposed in the article of your link is very similar to mine, I will study this article carefully.
If I don't get away with the solution in the article I'll try to post a short, understandable example code but it won't be easy.

Comment: What do you use as a key? Not the `index` of a `v-for` I hope.

Comment: No of course I didn't use the index 
I used a unique key built by concatenating several ids from my data, taking care that it is impossible for there to be 2 identical.

Comment: Alright, did you didn't fall into the typical trap! Still, not sure why your whole table re-renders but a memoization can be a way to improve, still the main issue is the table here IMO. Another solution would be to add some pagination and lower the amount of rows/columns.

Comment: No possibility to add a pagination because of the specifications, on the other hand I will implement an infinite scroll with loading of data as the user scrolls, it seems that this is the solution adopted most often for UIs that display a lot of data like on twitter or youtube.

But I already want to fix the problem that causes the entire array to load on every event.